# NHibernate - Generate Domain from Database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ssis, dns

I know its possible to generate the database tables from the domain model.  But is there any way of doing things the other way.  I have a totally awful database (worst I have ever seen).  Its sharded (16 Shards!!), split across multiple postgres databases (all on the same server) with foreign key relations like urn:dbtable:guid.

Its proving a major pain in the ass to migrate using SSIS so I want to use NHibernate, read the data into objects and rewrite to a SQL Server database in blissful data-architectural harmony.

Is there any way to scan the current DB using NH or other and build a domain model and mappings?

Thanks!

Comment: No tool will generate a domain model. Only a datamodel can be generated from a database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[NHibernate Mapping Generator](https://github.com/rvrn22/nmg)**
 - A simple utility to generate NHibernate mapping files and corresponding domain classes from existing DB tables

It's free.